# Simple product with custom options in magento bundled product

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to create a bundled product with set of simple products which have custom options (like colours,size etc),
But the custom options for a particular simple product doesn't seems to be appearing on the product page.

This is what I have tried so far.

1.Created simple products with with custom options
2.Created a bundled product.
3.Added simple products in step1 to bundled product in step2.

This is the result 
In the bundled product page no custom option for simple product included in the bundle is displayed.

This is what I am trying to get 
In the bundled product each simple product should have its own custom option selection

Example
Simple Product 1 - Shirt (size, colour)
Simple Product 2 - Shoes (size)
Simple Product 3 - Sunglass

Bundled Product 1 - Shirt + Shoes + Sunglass

But in the Bundled Product 1, I cannot select size/colour for shirt or size for Shoes

Is there anyway to implement this by tweaking the template to show the custom option of each simple product added to the bundle ?

I found this paid extension to implement this (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bundle-products-custom-options.html), but I am looking for a free alternative.

Comment: not enough understandable where you facing the problem, any code that you tried should share

Comment: I have updated the question to include detailed example, please advise.

Comment: @Hareendranath Did you get any solution ?